# Django: Form is not valid

Tags: python, django, forms

I am currently struggling to get my form to work properly. I created the form manually (template.html) and I can see all the data when I call it with print(request.POST) (in views.py - checkout) however form.is_valid(): (in views.py - checkout) doesn't work. Means my form is not valid.

I think the issue is, that I created the form manually and combined it with a model form where I want after validating my data with form.valid() save it in. Can anyone of you guys help me with my problem, why it's not valid?

template.html

```
<form action="{% url 'checkout:reserve_ticket' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for ticket in event.tickets.all %}
    <p>
        {{ ticket.name }} for {{ ticket.price_gross }} with quantity:
        <input type="hidden" name="order_reference" value="123456af">
        <input type="hidden" name="ticket" value="{{ ticket.id }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="ticket_name" value="{{ ticket.name }}">
        <input type="number" name="quantity" max="{{ ticket.event.organiser.max_quantity_per_ticket }}" placeholder="0">
    </p>
{% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
</form>
```

models.py

```
class ReservedItem(models.Model):
    order_reference = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        unique=True
    )
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(
        Ticket,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='reserved_tickets'
    )
    ticket_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

forms.py

```
class ReserveForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = ReservedItem
    fields = ['order_reference', 'ticket', 'ticket_name', 'quantity']
```

views.py - events

```
# Create your views here.
class EventDetailView(DetailView):

    context_object_name = 'event'

    def get_object(self):
        organiser = self.kwargs.get('organiser')
        event = self.kwargs.get('event')
        queryset = Event.objects.filter(organiser__slug=organiser)
        return get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=event)
```

views.py - checkout

```
def reserve_ticket(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReserveForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Hello World")
            return redirect("https://test.com")
    else:
        print("back to homepage")
```

Comment: Check `form.errors` to see why the form is invalid.

Comment: Aha very good tipp: <ul class="errorlist"><li>quantity<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul> Do you know if it's possible to give quantity a default value 0 if it's not filled out?

Comment: Maybe use `default=0` in the model?

Comment: Or you can do so by overriding the `__init__()` in ModelForm, and set `self.fields['quantity'].initial = 0`

Comment: Thank you guys. I will go for the default=0  
Thank you for all the help!